# Image is showing in wordpress localhost uploads folder but not updating in wordpress media library (wp dashboard))

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to upload image using wp custom template in child theme but when i upload any image. It appears in "E:\Xamp\htdocs\website\wp-content\uploads\2019\10" but not uploaded to wp dashboard media library.

I'M NOT ALLOWED TO USE ANY PLUGIN FOR THIS TASK.

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    if(! function_exists('wp_handle_upload')){
        require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }
    $uploadfile = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($uploadfile);
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false );

    $moveupload = wp_handle_upload($uploadfile,$upload_overrides);
    if($moveupload && ! isset($moveupload['error'])){
        echo "</Pre";
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $moveupload);
        print_r($moveupload);
        echo "Post/>";
    }else{
        echo $moveupload['error'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Can try out another piece of code here:
--------------------------
$upload_overrides = array( "test_form" => false );

$uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload ($file, $upload_overrides);

if( isset( $uploaded_file ["file"] )) {
    $file_name_and_location = $uploaded_file ["file"];
    $file_title_for_media_library = $title;

    $attachment = array(
        "post_mime_type" => $uploaded_file_type,
        "post_title" => addslashes( $file_title_for_media_library ),
        "post_content" => "",
        "post_status" => "inherit"
    );

    if( ! is_null( $post )) {
        if ( ! is_numeric( $post )) {
            $post = $post->ID;
        } // if ()

        $attachment ['post_parent'] = $post;
    } // if ()

    $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location );

    require_once( ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/image.php" );

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $file_name_and_location );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, $attach_data );
} // if ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files into the wp-content/uploads won't show up in the Media Library , those media ID's needs to be there in the database to show up in the Media Library.

If you already have files in the uploads folder and want to add them into the database

But this is not the correct solution instead fix the permissions issue for that uploads folder.

Thanks

Comment: as stated in my question i'm not allowed to use any plugin. I want to do this using custom code. Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by using custom php code.

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["file"]["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
$filename = $upload['file'];
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
// print_r($filename);
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```